# LWC - Adding elements to a Map

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am adding elements to a map but they don't seem to be appearing:

JS:

```
import { getObjectInfo, getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

@track _mapRecordTypeIdToName = [];

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;


renderedCallback() {
    if (this.objectInfo && this.objectInfo.data && this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos && (this._mapRecordTypeIdToName.length == 0 || this._mapRecordTypeIdToName.length == undefined)) {
        this.getRecordTypeIds();
    }
}


getRecordTypeIds() {
    const objEntries = Object.entries(this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos);
    window.console.log('objEntries: ', objEntries);
    let mapRecordTypes = [];
    let test = new Map();
    for (let [k, v] of objEntries) {
        test.set(v.name.toLowerCase(), v.recordTypeId);
        mapRecordTypes.push({ 'name': v.name.toLowerCase(), 'recordtypeid': v.recordTypeId });
    }
    window.console.log('mapRecordTypes: ' + JSON.stringify(mapRecordTypes)); //populates
    window.console.log('test: ' + JSON.stringify(test)); //empty
    this._mapRecordTypeIdToName = mapRecordTypes;
  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the [`JSON.stringify()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) (emphasis mine)

> All the other Object instances (including `Map`, `Set`, `WeakMap`, and `WeakSet`) will have **only their enumerable properties** serialized.
> Enumerable properties are visited using the same algorithm as `Object.keys`, which has a well-defined order and is stable across implementations.

When you add elements to a Map or to a Set, they are not stored as *properties*, indeed if after adding something to a map (or set) you try `console.log(Object.keys(mapInstance));` you'll get an empty array.
Therefore `console.log(JSON.stringify(mapInstance));` will always output `{}`.

The good news is that you almost never need to call `JSON.stringify()` in [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log), because it takes multiple parameters. Just try the following code and you'll see the values in the map:

```js
console.log('mapRecordTypes: ', mapRecordTypes);
console.log('test: ', test);
```